# How does this method perform in Big O notation?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, big-o

Below method "getValue" parses a String, builds a Map based on the String and returns a value associated with the key.
Is performance of method below "getValue" O(n) squared ?

I'm basing this on because everytime a new key value string is added it needs to be parsed and then the item is added to the Map.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MeasureBigO {

    private static final String testString = "keyTest=keyValue";

    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println(getValue("keyTest"));

    }

    private static String getValue(String key){

        Map<String, String> config = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();
        List<String> configItems = Arrays.asList(testString.split(","));

        for (String configItem : configItems) {
            configItem = configItem.trim();
            List<String> keyValuesPairs = Arrays.asList(configItem.split("="));

            try {
                config.put(keyValuesPairs.get(0).trim(), keyValuesPairs.get(1).trim());
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe){
                return null;
            }
        }

        return config.get(key);

    }

}
```

Comment: @TheLostMind: Good thing the constant doesn't change depending on the use cases, then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting up the string into list items will be O(n), relative to the size of the string.

Splitting up those items into pairs will be O(n*m), relative to the number of pairs (n, which relates to the length of the source string previously) and the size of each string (m). In practice we can probably assume that the size of each string will be negligible compared to the number of pairs.

Adding these to the hashmap will be O(n), relative to the number of pairs.
Assuming there isn't some issue with above-normal hash-collisions, retrieving the value will be approximately O(1).

Since all the `n`'s here relate to the same thing, We have O(n) + O(n*m) + O(n) + O(1). As we ignore lower orders when calculating order of complexity, this would be O(n*m). However, as said above, we'd expect the `m` of scanning to find the key to be negligible, especially with a fix mentioned below, so we'd just say O(n).

Another way of looking at this is that the first operation takes `c₀ * n + k₀` where c₀ is a constant amount of work done per item, and k₀ is a constant amount of work for the whole operation. The next takes `c₁ * n * m + k₁`, the next `c₂ * n + k₂`, and the final lookup `c₃ * 1`. Adding `k₄` as the constant overhead of the method itself, we have:

`c₀ * n + k₀ + c₁ * n * m + k₁ + c₂ * n + k₂ + c₃ * 1 + k₄`

Which equals:

`(c₁ * n * m) + (c₀ + c₂) * n + c₃ + k₀ + k₁ + k₂ + k₄`

And removing the lower orders gives us a time proportional to `n * m`, or to `n` if we can ignore `m` as negligible. Hence again O(n * m) or O(n) depending on whether we can ignore the size of each key-value pair.

Two things worth noting here. The first is that replacing the call to `configItem.split("=")` with `configItem.split("=", 2)` both improves correctness (catching the case where a value contains an `=`), and also makes `m` proportional to the size of the key rather than the entire pair, giving us more confidence in assuming it's negligible (and indeed, in giving a minor performance improvement).

The second is that assuming the source set of key-value pairs doesn't change, then we could either create the hash-map on set-up, or on the first call to the method, and simply use it again on subsequent calls. This would then make the method O(1) with an initial O(n) set-up.

Conversely, if the source set does change, there's no point using the map at all, and one could simply return the value as soon as a matching key is found when iterating through the pairs; hence an O(n) method, but with smaller constants and on average only examining half the pairs for a successful match.

Answer (score 5):

The complexity of this algorithm is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of items in `configItems`.

- I base it on the format of `testString`: It can be split in `O(1)` time.
- The loop around `configItems` is proportional to `O(n)`.
- The other `split` operation with `configItem` is `O(1)` as well.

Apart from them you have instructions in your loop so in practice it is `C * O(n)` where `C` is some constant cost of them.

Comment: Are you sure about the split being O(1)? Surely it would be O(n) as it has to iterate through the string.

Comment: As I said in my answer I assume it from the format of the `String` in the question. Those strings are key-value pairs. There is no example for a `configItem` but I can deduce from the name that it is a key-value pair as well. So it should be `O(1)`.

Comment: Yes. And finding the points at which to split the first string into pairs is O(n). Finding the points within each pair to split into keys and values is also O(n), thought probably negligible in all likely cases. The result on the whole remains a matter of O(n) since the n of each relates to the same thing, but splitting is an O(n) operation.

Comment: In theory yes, but we have a concrete use case here.

Comment: @JonHanna If I understand you correctly, you are mixing two different n's togehter. First is number of items in list, second the number of characters in string.

Comment: And the latter can be treated as quasi-constant.

Comment: And in that concrete case the `split` method first examines `testString[0]` to see if it equals `,`, then `testString[1]`, and so on until `testString[15]`. That's O(n). The next `split` has the same complexity. The only thing that's different in this concrete case is that we know the `n` of the loop is `1`, so we could claim **that** part was O(1), though it's reasonable to assume that we need the complexity for different values of  `testString` (otherwise we could just replace the whole thing with a constant time `return key == "keyTest" ? "keyValue" : null;`)

Comment: I'm starting with three `n`s, because I'm considering the complexity of the whole method, so I need to consider what happens in the whole method. I'm then noting that one `n` relates to the other `n`, because the more pairs that exist, the longer the source string (and since we do one and then the other, we're O(n) overall). I'm also noting that the other `n` is probably negligible. Hence my answer "O(n * m), but as m is probably negligible, then really O(n)". You're calling an O(n) operation O(1) on no basis.